# how to bulk share reports in salesforce

Tags: lightning, salesforce1-app, salesforcedx

I recently started using Salesforce (lightning version). While working on a test report I was looking at ways I can share my report. I came across this link >https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rd_folders_share_enhanced.htm&type=5 which talks about users, groups and roles. Now the problem here is if I have to create a group I will have to manually add those members which is not feasible in my organization as the count is in thousands. So is there a way of sharing reports based on profiles for eg everyone in HR is able to view the report rather than me having to add them individually?

Comment: Do all the HR have a common role?

Comment: by role you mean same set of permissions? some of them might have different permissions but most of them will be similar